# Angularjs Share data between two modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to share a service between two controllers in two different modules. I've seen posts that lead me to believe I'm on the right track, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751172/angularjs-modules-scope-sharing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594140/how-to-share-data-between-two-modules-in-angular-js). But I'm obviously missing something. Here is my code and a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqBdbY?editors=101).

The index is being set okay, but isSidebarActive isn't being fired automatically like one would expect. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**index.js**

```
angular
    .module('app', ['app.layout', 'app.sidebar']);
angular
    .module('app.layout', [])
    .service('layoutService', function() {
        var vm = this;
        var sidebarStatus = null;
        vm.isSidebarActive = function() {
            console.log('isSidebarActive: ' + (sidebarStatus ? 'true' : 'false'));
            return sidebarStatus;
        };
        vm.setSidebarStatus = function(status) {
            console.log('setSidebarStatus: ' + (status ? 'true' : 'false'));
            sidebarStatus = status;
        };
    })
    .controller('ShellController', ['layoutService', function(layoutService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.isSidebarActive = function() {
            return layoutService.isSidebarActive();
        }
    }]);

angular
    .module('app.sidebar', ['app.layout'])
    .controller('SidebarController', ['layoutService', function(layoutService) {
        var vm = this;
        var index = null;
        vm.setIndex = function(i) {
            index = i;
            layoutService.setSidebarStatus(i > 0);
            console.log('setIndex: ' + index);
        };
        vm.isIndex = function (i) {
            return index === i;
        };
    }]);
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ShellController as shell">
    <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="shell.isSidebarActive">active</div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="shell.isSidebarActive">non-active</div>
  <div/>
  <div ng-controller="SidebarController as sidebar">
    <a class="btn" ng-click="sidebar.setIndex(1)">active</a>
    <a class="btn" ng-click="sidebar.setIndex(0)">non-active</a>
  <div/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="ShellController as shell">
        <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="shell.isSidebarActive()">active</div>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="shell.isSidebarActive()">non-active</div>
      <div/>
      <div ng-controller="SidebarController as sidebar">
        <a class="btn" ng-click="sidebar.setIndex(1)">active</a>
        <a class="btn" ng-click="sidebar.setIndex(0)">non-active</a>
      <div/>
    </body>
```

You must call the function `shell.isSidebarActive()` in `ng-show` and `ng-hide`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjpeoR

Comment: Remove array from your second module.

Comment: Thank you, that took me far to long to figure out.